# How to convert a String to HEX or Binary or decimal

Tags: c, string, binary, hex

I have a string like this  "10100010" that's equal to 162 decimal or 0xA2 hex. I need to fin a way to calculate one of those values in C. Or just a way to obtain this in C : 0b(string) - 0b10100010

Ive tried to convert each bit (char) to int by doing this : String[0] - '0' , and use a loop to mannualy calculate the value of the binary number, something like this, but it didn't work..

```
for (i=0,n=n_c; i<n_c; i++,n--)
{
    decimal_value=decimal_value+ pow( (val[i]-'0') , (n-1) );

    printf("%d ",  pow( (int) ((val[i]-'0')) , (n-1)));
}
```

in this particular case n_c = 6 (6 bits). If the string is bigger than 8 bits, I have another problem, but let's focus on this "simple" case for now.

could you help me?

Comment: Your code (besides the question of some errors I think you might have), might not do what you hope. Do you know any bit-operations (i.e. ` 1 << i`)?

Comment: Don't use floating point functions for integer calculations.

Answer (score 2):

there is a example of bin to dec:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(){ 
        char a[] = "100";
        char b[] = "100";
        char c[] = "0x11";
        int x, y, z; 
        x = strtol( a, NULL, 10 ); 
        y = strtol( b, NULL, 2 ); 
        z = strtol( c, NULL, 16 ); 
        printf( "x = %d\n", x );
        printf( "y = %d\n", y );
        printf( "z = %d\n", z );

    }
```

output：x = 100 ;y = 4 ;z = 17

Comment: Nice work using a standard function for the job. However, please fix your `#include` lines.

Comment: Assigning a `long` to an `int` may generate a warning. As you are on the safe side, you should explicitly cast here. Also the hex string should not work.

Comment: @Olaf "the hex string should not work" is not consistent with the C specification of `strtol()`  "If the value of base is 16, the characters `0x` or `0X` may optionally precede the sequence of letters and digits" C11dr §7.22.1.4 3  `strtol( "0x11", NULL, 16 );` will convert to 17 just fine.

Comment: @chux: Thanks, I missed the last sentence. Anyway, the conversion-issue still holds true. On POSIX64 this will be a servere issue for normal code with arbitrary input. Also for other than decimal values, unsigned types might be more appropriate (with `strtoul`), but that is a detail.

Answer (score 0):

I think using bit operations might get you a better result.

The following code isn't the most optimized nor creative, but demonstrates a direct approach to the problem using bitwise operators (`<<` and `|`).

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*
  Returns the binary number found at the beginning of the string (if any).
  No error checks are performed
*/
unsigned long parse_binary_string(char* str) {
  unsigned long value = 0;
  while (1) {
    if (*str == '0')
      value = value << 1;
    else if (*str == '1')
      value = (value << 1) | 1;
    else
      break;
    str++;
  }
  return value;
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
  char string[] = "01101010";
  printf("The result for %s is %lu\n", string, parse_binary_string(string));
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The reason why your method does not work is 
>   1. You need make use of (i)*2^(n-1)
>   2. You make use of wrong way to print the result.
>
> The pow function's definition is   double pow(double x, double y);

```
Pls try this:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int n_c = 6;
    char val[10]={'0','1','0','1','0','1','0',};
    double decimal_value = 0;
    int n;
    for (i=0,n=n_c; i<n_c; i++,n--)
    {   
        decimal_value=decimal_value+ pow( (val[i]-'0')*2 ,(n-1) );
        printf("%lf \n",  pow( (((val[i]-'0'))*2) , (n-1)));
    }   
    printf("%lf \n", decimal_value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best to use `strtol()`, yet if you want to roll your own code:

An easy way to convert a string of base N characters into an integer to walk though each digit and add it to the sum which has been multiplied by the base.

OP will still needed to add some code and determine how to handle bad input.  Something to get you started.

```
// convert '0' --> 0, 'A' --> 10, 'z' --> 35, etc.
// return -1 on failure  
int covert_char_to_digit(char ch) {
  TBD code
}

int string_to_int(const char *s, int base) {
  if (test_if_valid_base(base)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid base %d\n", base);
    return 0;
  }
  int sum = 0;
  while (*s) {
    int ch = covert_char_to_digit(*s);
    if (ch < 0 || ch >= base) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Invalid digit\n");
      return 0;
    }

    // Does OP want to detect pending overflow
    // Here is a good place for such code.

    sum = sum*base + ch;
    s++;
  }
  return sum;
}
```